# Disable Port 137 and 139 when web hosting

Tags: asp.net, port, web-hosting

I'm hosting an ASP.Net website though a shared interserver server and I've just got an vulnerability assessment report from a trusted third party saying ports 137 and 139 are visible externally.

I've been trying for hours to figure this out (googling, opening tickets, searching forums) and I can't find anything that helps.

Any idea what I can do here? How can I close/disable these ports? Is this something I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no access to the administration of the server (either with Remote Desktop access or a configuration panel), you can't close ports from inside your application.

If you have access to the firewall (again, either via Windows or the hosting's configuration panel), you should block access to the desired ports. These ports are used by NetBIOS, which your application most probably doesn't need.

Comment: Thanks, very much appreciated